# getting null in the get set method using JAVA

Tags: java, get, set

I am doing multiple window java form.

So basically my user is required to registered an account.

**BELOW is my get set class**

```
public class SecureData {

 private String reguserName;
 private String password ;
 private String userName;
 private String regpassword ;
 private String confirmPassword ;
 private String email ;
 private String contact ;
 private String question1Text ;
 private String question2Text;
 private String answer1Text;
// private String answer2Text ;
 private String userDetails;


  public String getregUserName() {
    return reguserName;
}

public void setregUserName(String reguserName) {
    this.reguserName = reguserName;
}

public String getregPassword() {
    return regpassword;
}

public void setregPassword(String regpassword) {
    this.regpassword = regpassword;
}


 public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Below is a portion code for my registration class

```
String UserName = nameField.getText();
String password = passwordField.getText();
String confirmPassword = confirmField.getText();
String email = emailField.getText();
String contact = contactField.getText();
String question1Text = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
//String question2Text = question2Filed.getSelectedItem().toString();
String answer1Text = answer1Field.getText();
//String answer2Text = answer2Field.getText();
String userDetails = "";



sd.setUserName(UserName);
sd.setPassword(password);
sd.setConfirmPassword(confirmPassword);
sd.setContact(contact);
sd.setQuestion1Text(question1Text);
//sd.setQuestion2Text(question2Text);
sd.setAnswer1Text(answer1Text);
```

And lastly...i have a third JAVA class which is perform some function in another new window form

```
try {
    SecureData secureinfo = new SecureData();
    String UserNameLog = secureinfo .getUserName();
    String PassLog = secureinfo.getPassword();
    System.out.println(PassLog);

    String pidviduser;
    String pidvidpass;

    //cREATING hval2 NOW
    pidvidpass = PIDstring+":"+VIDstring + ":" +PassLog;
```

**However** my problem is that my password in the third java class is null.
i roughly understand is due to to the
 private SecureData secureinfo = new SecureData(); but is there an example or so to solve this issue of mine?

Appreciate if anyone can advice on this.Thank in advance.

Comment: Ideally the third class should be using a `SecureData` POJO from the registration portion of your code.  But so much code is missing, this is as much as I can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already set the values in your `Registration` class, the second class in your question. The next approach would be passing your Object `sd` to your **Third Class**. As Stephen C said, It will be literally a null values in your attributes because you created a `new SecureData()` and you didn't set it's field values. So, you don't need to create `SecureData()`, just pass your `sd` object in the third class. like this in your **3rd Class**:

```
public void someMethod(SecureData sd) {
 String UserNameLog = sd.getUserName();
    String PassLog = sd.getPassword();
    System.out.println(PassLog);

    String pidviduser;
    String pidvidpass;

    //cREATING hval2 NOW
    pidvidpass = PIDstring+":"+VIDstring + ":" +PassLog;
}
```

and in your **2nd Class** the Registration class:

```
sd.setUserName(UserName);
sd.setPassword(password);
sd.setConfirmPassword(confirmPassword);
sd.setContact(contact);
sd.setQuestion1Text(question1Text);
//sd.setQuestion2Text(question2Text);
sd.setAnswer1Text(answer1Text);

ThirdClass third = new ThirdClass();
third.someMethod(sd);
```

I just instantiated your `Third Class` to access your **someMethod(SecureData sd)** method assuming that it is the design of your code.

Comment: haha ..thanks.. i going give it a try. and thanks for all the guys who helped also.

Answer (score 0):

In your last class, you are creating a brand new `SecureInfo` object and then immediately trying to read the password.  Naturally, it is `null`.  You haven't set the password field *in this instance*.  You set it in a *different* instance.

Comment: maybe needs to share the previously created `SecureData`, but who knows

Comment: i will give a try guys.